# iOS: General tips on managing memory for large data sets on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, memory-management

I'm currently working on an iPhone app that is fairly data intensive. It downloads about 300kb of XML data, holds this entirely in memory in arrays and dictionaries of model objects and performs various operations on this data that likely cause it to grow a few times in size.

How do you go about managing data sets of this sort of size? Would you use core data to manage this, or would you simply hold this data in memory as I have done and manipulate it that way? There is never a need for me to actually persist any of this data on the device.

Additionally, should I be concerned about holding this amount of data in memory?

Just looking for some general advice here and wondering what others have done in similar situations. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: doesn't sound like a real large amount of data. However, I'd first of all profile it with instruments and see how large the memory footprint is for all the objects. Then decide to migrate to Core-Data or if you like the detail work direct sqlite.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I merge this XML data with other client-held static data hard-coded into the app, which probably brings the whole data set in at over 1MB. For convenience I'm just hard-coding the client-held data into model objects in the app and am wondering if perhaps core data is a better option here..

Comment: if the rest of your app doesn't eat up all the available memory I'd stick to your current solution. However Core-Data will need some time to be implemented properly. And like Alex Reynolds mentioned you can keep managed objects in memory with pre fetching.

Comment: You might think about how much this data store might change as your app is upgraded. If your data are well-structured but the content is volatile, a Core Data approach might help ease the migration process. You also get access to `NSFetchedResultsController` and other helper classes that facilitate easy access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping the 300 kB of data in memory, consider putting the XML data into a Core Data store.

[Faulting](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html) is used with Core Data predicates ("searches") to "lazy-load" information — i.e., you're only pulling data from the store when you need it, which reduces memory and performance overhead.

I suspect that pre-fetching some of your more frequently re-used data can help your app with performance. Read the [Core Data Performance](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html) docs for more info.

Comment: Because I'm performing a lot of operations on the data (particularly graphing ops), I'm concerned that going the core data route may cause a performance hit?